# How to reuse code segment with blazor component?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I don't know if its possible, but i have a switch statement allowing to different components based on the value. However i can see that i would like to use this switch statement, is there an option in blazor to reuse it?

This is the code i am thinking

```
@page "/"

@foreach (var widget in _components)
{
    switch (widget)
    {
        case WidgetA:
            <WidgetA/>
            break;
        case WidgetB:
            <WidgetB/>
            break;
    }
}
```

However I would like to use it multiple time, is there a way to store this in a function I try the follow, but it doesnt load

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @foreach (var widget in _components21)
            {
                switche(widget);
            }
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @foreach (var widget in _components22)
            {
                switche(widget);
            }
        </div>
    </div>

    private string switche(IComponent widget)
    {
        string html = "";
        switch (widget)
        {
            case WidgetA:
                html = "<WidgetA/>";
                break;
            case <WidgetB/>:
                html = "<WidgetB/>";
                break;
        }
        return html;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a parent component that houses both widgets, then in the property of the parent component you can have a parameter called WidgetType that defines what widget you actually want to use.

Parent Widget:

```
@if(WidgetType == "A"){
  <WidgetA>
}else{
  <WidgetB>
}
@code{
    [Parameter] public string WidgetType {get; set;}
}
```

Then in you would use this in your for loop

```
@foreach (var widget in _components)
{
    <ParentWidget @WidgetType=widget.WidgetType>
}
```